# mongoDB bindIp to allow connection from lambda through VPC

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a MongoDB running in my ec2. Currently my MongoDB `mongod.conf` is as below:

```
net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

As you can see, it only allows local connection. But currently, it's not a problem since my nodejs app is running in the same ec2 instance. However, we're moving our code to serverless lambda, so we will need our code in lambda to be able to connect to this MongoDB. Our lambda will connect through VPC to this ec2 instance.

Do I need to change the `bindIp` to some other values to allow this, or leave it as it is?

Comment: Try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I need to change my `bindIp` to `0.0.0.0`. I know many people will say this is a security issue, but since I configured the security group of the instance where my MongoDB is running to only allow connection to port 27017` from the same VPC, I believe this should make my MongoDB secure.

Some information which may help others out there, since I'm using the serverless framework, I need to add my security group id and subnet id to my `serverless.yaml` configuration file, as below:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-02XXXXXXXXXX
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-eXXXXXX
```